# Not able to create an edit link for an excel file using microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to create an editable link for an excel file stored in my Personal Ondrive account. According to the documentation [Microsoft-Graph-Onedrive-docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink), I should be able to use createLink API with payload as `{"type": "edit", "view: "anonymous"}`. But even after doing that the link opens a read-only excel file in excel online.
How do I open an editable excel file in excel online

I am using Personal Onedrive and calling the APIs via Microsoft graph explorer

Comment: What is the response for the request?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `.doc` or `.xls` document you can not edit that. You'll need one of the newer Word, Excel formats like: `.docx` or `.xlsx`.